# ionic state did not run correctly

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there anything wrong with the following ionic code,caz the url './#/tab/guiderRegister' seems not working properly, which only shows the header. but './#/tab/register'and './#/tab/signup' can work.

//ionic state

```
      .state('tabs.register', {
        url:'/register',
        views:{
          'home-tab':{
            templateUrl:'./register',
            controller:'homeController'
          }
        }

      })
       .state('tabs.guiderRegister', {
        url:'/guiderRegister',
        views:{
          'home-tab':{
            templateUrl:'./guiderRegister',
            controller:'homeController'
          }
        }

      })
       .state('tabs.signup', {
        url:'/signup',
        views:{
          'home-tab':{
            templateUrl:'./signup',
            controller:'homeController'
          }
        }

      })
```

//html

```
                    <div class="row registerChoose">
                         <div>
                           <div class="chooseEG"><a href="./#/tab/register">Expat</a></div>
                           <div class="chooseEG"><a href="./#/tab/guiderRegister">Guider</a></div>
                           <div class="chooseEG"><a href="./#/tab/signup">signup</a></div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
```

//guiderRegister

```
<ion-view view-title="Guider Register" hide-tabs>

   <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
       <a href="./#/tab/signup"><button class="button button-icon">Signup</button></a>
   </ion-nav-buttons>  

   <ion-content class="">

           <div class="list">
                <form name="guiderRegister" action="./postGuiderRegister" method="post" id="guiderRegister">

                            <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </label>

                            <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                            </label>

                            <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            </label>

                            <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="password" placeholder="Password Again" name="password_confirmation">
                            </label>


                            <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="text" placeholder="Nationality" name="nationality" >
                            </label>


                             <label class="item item-input">
                                  <textarea  placeholder="* Intruduce Yourself" name="constantIntro"  style="min-height:6em;">
                                  </textarea>
                             </label>

<!--                             <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="text" placeholder="Service Location" name="location">
                            </label> -->
                <ion-toggle ng-model="serviceLocation">Service Location</ion-toggle>

                <ion-radio ng-model="myLocation" ng-show="serviceLocation"  ng-repeat="destination in destinationSettings" ng-value="destination.text" name="location">
                     @{{ destination.text }}
                </ion-radio> 


                             <label class="item item-input">
                              <input type="text" placeholder="Charge" name="change">
                             </label>                                                        

                              <ion-toggle ng-model="serviceProvided">Service Provided</ion-toggle>
                              <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in provideList"
                                            ng-model="item.checked" 
                                            ng-checked="item.checked"
                                            ng-show="serviceProvided">
                                @{{ item.text }}
                              </ion-checkbox> 

                        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                </form>  
            </div>




  </ion-content>


<ion-footer-bar align-title="middle" class="bar-stable">
    <input type="submit" class="title button"  value="submit"  form="guiderRegister">
</ion-footer-bar>  
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Why the dot(.) in your `templateURL`?

Comment: The root url, it can work in other conditions. So I think it's not the problem, thanks